# Selenium Frameworks and Remote Testing, recommended framework?

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver

I installed and played around with Selenium WebDriver on Visual Studio 2012 (C#) last week and was very impressed by how easy it was to automate browser testing. I now want to find out if I can expand the functionality. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

- Run Selenium WebDriver tests on remote machines, ideally managed by a central control machine.
- Integrate test results with Quality Center or Test Manager
- How to automate tasks such as application installer? I realise Selenium can't do this.
- Utilize an existing framework that already has functions for common tasks such as batch testing, logging, copying files, etc.

I apologize if my questions are a bit broad but I'm certain others have tried to achieve this with Selenium before.
Your help is very appreciated,
John

Comment: Selenium can do all of those things EXCEPT (as you noted), the application installer tasks.  For those, couldn't you just use the `Scheduler` in Windows for that?

Comment: Thanks for that Brian. Maybe I wasn't clear but I was looking for specific tools to achieve what I listed in my question.

 - How exactly can I run Selenium WebDriver on remote machines? Is
   Selenium RC the best way?
 - Is there some plugin that enables me to integrate Selenium with
   Quality Centre or Test Manager?
 - Are there any existing frameworks that contain function to do common
   tasks such as batch testing, logging, create files and folders, etc.

Any specific pointers would be very appreciated.
John

Comment: @bearaman You can make use of selenium grid to run the tests on remote machine, rather than using typical Selenium RC Server